# How to add static files to an Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

How can I add JSON or TOML files in an Electron app for deployment? The following code works in development environment, but does not after packaging by `electron-packager`.

```
var presets = toml.parse(fs.readFileSync('presets.toml','utf8'));
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?  How does it "not work"? Does it error? Does it do nothing?

Comment: File is not found. I don't know where the root of readFileSync in the deployed app is.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [guide](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md) that took me way too long to find, the Electron team patched the `fs` module to provide a "virtual file system" under the root (`/`).

That means your file is accessible at `fs.readFileSync('/presets.toml');` (notice the forward slash).

Answer (score 0):

I went crazy till I found this one.
The problem is not adding it because it's already added.
Problem is finding base path after packaging.

So here it is:

```
const { app } = window.require('electron').remote;;
console.log(app.getAppPath());
```

Also, as you can see, if you're using React you need to use `window.require` instead of regular `require` (it throws nasty error otherwise).

Found about this here:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3204#issuecomment-151000897